# Dynamic Query using Linq To SQL According Multiple Fields

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic, dynamic-data, dynamic-sql

Hi Experts
I have a special question About dynamic Linq to Sql.
Consider we want to search in a table according two fields**(LetterNo(string) and LetterDate(Datetime))**
.OK the problem is user can enter on of that fields or even both.

I searched in the internet and found "Linq.Dynamic" library in ScottGu weblog.but in that library if we want to use SqlParameter in exported command we should use **@0** and **param** for that.problem is I don't know how many fields user entered.

I want use one query for that and no external tool like "Linq Kit PredicateBuilder".

If I create my query string Manually(and execute using ExecuteCommand) then I will abdicate SqlParameter and risk of Sql Injenction growing up.
How Can do that?
thanks

Comment: Could you restructure your question for readability? THis is just one big paragraph. Also add in what you already have that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are wanting to do something like the following:

```
IQueryable<Letter> query = context.Letters;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LetterNo))
    query = query.Where(letter => letter.LetterNo == LetterNo);
If (LetterDate.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(letter => letter.LetterDate == LetterDate);
```

When you execute query, it will combine the necessary expressions and issue a single query to the database based on the user's input.